# CSV every day upload in to the same table

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, teradata

I would need to upload a csv file to a teradata database every day.
I receive this file every morning to an ftp server, and I want to pull the data and upload it to teradata,
So far I have managed to pull the data from the ftp, save it, add a date column and fill up the null values with a dummy.

```
df2['WM_ID']=df2['WM_ID'].fillna('999999')
```

does the trick, but it also gives me grief to use another method.(does it anyway)

now I got to the part where I would have to upload the data to an existing table. I manage to make the connection:

```
create_engine('teradata://'+ user +':' + pasw + '@'+ host +'/' + '?authentication=LDAP')
```

this connects to the main database but the table is in a subdatabase (not sure if this is a word) lets call it `user_dev`. Lets call the table `test`

I have a csv with 10 colums and around 4000 rows every day.
There are also a few null values (not in primary key).

Now I am not really sure about the declarative base and the rest, I tried to use them but I failed.

```
td_engine = create_engine('teradata://'+ user +':' + pasw + '@'+ host +'/' + '?authentication=LDAP')
print (td_engine)

connection = td_engine.raw_connection()

print ('logged in to teradata')
def Load_Data(file_name):
    data = genfromtxt(file_name, delimiter=',', skip_header=1, converters={0: lambda s: str(s)})
    return data.tolist()

Base = declarative_base()

class pb_test(Base):
  __Tablename__= "test"

  entry_date = Column(Date)
  WID = Column(VARCHAR(50),primary_key=True)
  User_IP_co = Column(VARCHAR(50))
  User_S = Column(VARCHAR(50))
  Visitors = Column(Integer)
  Reg = Column(Integer)
  Real = Column(Integer)
  Regi = Column(Integer)
  First = Column(Integer)
  First_D = Column(Integer)



  def __repr__(self):
    return "(entry_date='%s', WID='%s', User_IP_co='%s', User_S='%s', Visitors='%s', Reg='%s', Real='%s', Regi='%s', First='%s', First_D='%s')" % (self.entry_date, self.WID, self.User_IP_Co, self.User_S, self.Visitors, self.Reg, self.Real, self.Regi, self.First, self.First_D)


yesterday = date.today() - timedelta(1)
FileToRead = pd.read_csv('Report20'+str(yesterday.strftime('%y%m%d'))+'.csv')
tableToWriteTo = 'USER_DEVELOPMENT.test'
#data.head()
df = pd.DataFrame(FileToRead)


listToWrite = df.to_dict(orient='records')

metadata = sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData(bind=td_engine,reflect=True)
table = sqlalchemy.Table(tableToWriteTo, metadata, autoload=True)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=td_engine)
session = Session()

connection.execute(table.insert(), listToWrite)

session.commit()

session.close()
```

Not sure what is going wrong, but I get this error message:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Class <class '__main__.test'> does not have a __table__ or __tablename__ specified and does not inherit from an existing table-mapped class.
```

Comment: `__Tablename__` != `__tablename__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your approach is a bit muddled. You define a declarative base and then fail to use it. If you want to go that route, then see this [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html). (And, as commented, the argument you want is **tablename**. Furthermore, you might need to use the **table_args** to specify the schema).

Alternatively, you could just define the table and its columns as you attempt to at the bottom. For details on this approach, see this [link](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html).

Given the simplicity of your task, I might choose option #2.

```
#table = sqlalchemy.Table(tableToWriteTo, metadata, autoload=True)
table = Table(
    'test',
    metadata,
    Column('WID', VARCHAR(50),primary_key=True),
    Column('entry_date', Date),
    Column('User_IP_co', VARCHAR(50)),
    Column('User_S', VARCHAR(50)),
    ...,
    schema='USER_DEVELOPMENT'
)
```